# Why does my trigger in HeidiSql not inser any information?

Tags: sql, triggers, mariadb

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tmVideo
    BEFORE INSERT ON messages 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE vurl VARCHAR(256);
        SET vurl = (SELECT url FROM videos WHERE videoId = NEW.mVideoId);
        IF new.mvideoId != NULL THEN INSERT INTO messagesvideos (messageId, videoId, url) VALUES (NEW.messageId, NEW.mvideoId, vurl);
        END IF;
    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I'm trying to save on the `messagesvideos` table all the messages that contain a video. I created this trigger but when I do the insert on the messages table I get no response.

Comment: HeidiSQL is just a client. What's interesting here is the actual DBMS. Add that and its version as a tag by [edit]ing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`null` is not a value, it's the lack thereof. You can't use `=` or `!=` to test for it, you should use the `is` operator instead:

```
IF new.mvideoId IS NOT NULL THEN 
    -- Here ----^
    INSERT INTO messagesvideos (messageId, videoId, URL)
    VALUES (NEW.messageId, NEW.mvideoId, vurl);
END IF;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's all working now!

Comment: @AmadorSanchezAlvarez glad to hear it. Please accept answers that do exactly what you want.